# SQL: Merge almost identical lines with start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following rows:

| id | status | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-17 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-22 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-01-23 | 2023-01-23 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-01-24 | 2023-01-26 |
| 111 | 0 | 2023-01-27 | 9999-12-31 |
| 222 | 0 | 2023-01-19 | 2023-01-22 |
| 222 | 0 | 2023-01-23 | 2023-01-27 |
| 222 | 0 | 2023-01-28 | 9999-12-31 |

I would like to transform the data in the following way:

| id | status | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-17 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-26 |
| 111 | 0 | 2023-01-27 | 9999-12-31 |
| 222 | 0 | 2023-01-19 | 9999-12-31 |

How can I write an SQL query for this?

P.s.

```
SELECT '111' AS Id, 0 AS Status, '2023-01-13'::date AS StartDate, '2023-01-17'::date AS EndDate UNION
SELECT '111', 1, '2023-01-18', '2023-01-22' UNION
SELECT '111', 1, '2023-01-23',  '2023-01-23' UNION
SELECT '111', 1, '2023-01-24',  '2023-01-26' UNION
SELECT '111', 0, '2023-01-27',  '9999-12-31' UNION
SELECT '222', 0, '2023-01-19', '2023-01-22' UNION
SELECT '222', 0, '2023-01-23',  '2023-01-27' UNION
SELECT '222', 0, '2023-01-28',  '9999-12-31'
```

Comment: Hi Kvv, can you explain better what exactly do you expect the query to do? to merge all rows with following dates? what behavior for status? what behavior for Id? can date repeat or overlap?

Comment: I had formatting issue. I think, now my question is clear.

Comment: Hi, still not very clear, please see the question I raised... also which RDBS? Postgresql?

Comment: I added the Postgres tag based on the casting syntax `'2023-01-17'::date`, which only Postgres supports as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group together consecutive rows having the same `id` and `status` - which reads like a gaps-and-islands problem.

Here is one way to do it by defining the groups with the difference of `row_numbers`s:

```
select id, status, min(startdate) startdate, max(enddate) enddate
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by startdate) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by id, status order by startdate) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by id, status, rn1 - rn2
order by id, min(startdate)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k70cnWh6)**

| id | status | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-17 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-26 |
| 111 | 0 | 2023-01-27 | 9999-12-31 |
| 222 | 0 | 2023-01-19 | 9999-12-31 |

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
select id, status, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from mytable
group by id, status, date_format(startdate, '%Y-%m'), date_format(enddate, '%Y-%m')
```

Result :

```
id  status  min(startdate)  max(enddate)
111 0   2023-01-13  2023-01-17
111 1   2023-01-18  2023-01-26
111 0   2023-01-27  9999-12-31
222 0   2023-01-19  2023-01-27
222 0   2023-01-28  9999-12-31
```

Comment: Not exactly. My expectation is like in my first post.